# Count variable in sas

Tags: count, sas

I am wanting to set a count variable for another variable (innings). Additionally I want the count variable to reset every time the innings variables changes from 1 to 2. For example

```
innings  count
1         1
1         2
1         3
1         4
1         5
1         6
1         7
1         8
1         9
1         10
2         1
2         2
2         3
2         4
2         5
2         6
2         7
2         8
2         10
2         11
2         12
1         1
1         2
1         3
1         4
1         5
1         6
```

I have tried the following code:

```
data T20_SCORECARD_data_innings;
   set T20_SCORECARD_data_innings;
   count + 1;
   by innings;
   if first.innings then count = 0;
run;
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ankit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is truly not sorted and simply grouped into bins, 1 and 2 then you can use your code but add the NOTSORTED option to your BY statement.

```
data T20_SCORECARD_data_innings;
  set T20_SCORECARD_data_innings;
  by innings NOTSORTED;
  count + 1;
  if first.innings then count = 0;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks Reeza- the NOTSORTED option worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In a datastep when you use the by clause the data needs to be sorted.  In your case it isn't.  If you change your data so the third group (second group of 1's) to 3's your code should work.

Comment: Thanks DCR- Appreciate the help